# Order by query using 2 columns using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Here is the sample of my database structure:

```
id |    name    |   role   |   login_status   |
-----------------------------------------------
 1      mark        user           1
 2      john       lawyer          0
 3      david       user           0
 4      erik       lawyer          0
```

What I want is to order them in such a way that the users with the `lawyer` role will be on the top of the list followed by the users with the value of `1` in the `login_status` column.

I used `orderBy('login_status','desc')` for the login_status column but i am having a hard time with the condition of the `role` column.

expected output:

```
- john
- erik
- mark
- david
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression for you criteria

```
->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN role ='lawyer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC")
->orderBy( 'login_status', 'DESC' );
```

Plain sql would be like

```
select *
from demo
order by CASE WHEN role ='lawyer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, login_status DESC
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d09406/1)

Or you can make your order clause even shorter like

```
order by role ='lawyer' DESC, login_status DESC
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d09406/2)

Comment: Can't you just have two orderBy one for role the other for login_status? Or will that not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION

```
select * from table where role='lawyer' order by login_status desc
UNION
select * from table where role!='lawyer' order by login_status desc
```